# The name of sub menu items wrap in the dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Because of the use of `position` the name of the "sub sub items" wrap. I have no idea how to work around this issue. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  background: #3d9ca8;
}

.menu-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .sub-menu,
  .flyout-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #3d9ca8;
  }

  .flyout {
    position: relative;
  }

  .flyout-nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sub-menu.css">
  <title>Sub Menus</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-container">
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Item 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="flyout"><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
              <ul class="flyout-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Item 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that you want sub sub item 1 to be all on one line?

Comment: No I just want the name of each list item to shown on one line, just like "sub item 1", "sub item 2", and "sub item 3"

Answer (score 0):

add a width to flyout-nav which is controlling the sub sub items

```
.flyout-nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can add `width: max-content;` to `.flyout-nav` but these are like hacks. I have no idea why "sub item 1", "sub item 2", and "sub item 3" displays well without the need of hacks.

Comment: if you put it on width: 100%, it will have the same width of the sub nav, your text is longer however on the sub sub nav so you will need to manually change the sizing to fit the text on one line

Answer (score -1):

You need `white-space:nowrap;` added to `.sub-menu,.flyout-nav`

Comment: @ShrewdStyle **Respectfully**, what we offer here as answers are not `hacks`. Yo are already utilizing CSS to modify the view of elements, and we offer additional CSS that will fix what you re asking for. Having a `width:100%` does not guarantee that your elements will be visible on one line. But then again it's up to you to treat additional CSS as a hack :) Good luck.

Comment: There is no need to use `width: 100%` I don't know who came up with that idea. I didn't even mention it. I was talking about `width: max-content;` which seems to fix the issue and there is no need to use white-space nowrap. Thanks anyway!